# ffmpeg: sliding overlay for filter comparison

Tags: ffmpeg, overlay, crop, video-processing

I am trying to get the effect demonstrated in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xrMZSLb_gPs

Most of the sliding overlay solutions I've seen are for a sliding fixed image, but not for a progressive crop of each part of the video.

I've tried doing:

```
ffmpeg -i video1.mp4 -i video2.mp4 \
 -filter_complex "[0]crop='min(iw*(1+n)/100,iw)':ih:0:0[left];[1]crop='max((1-n/100)*iw,1)':ih:1-'max((1-n/100)*iw,1)':0[right];[left][right]hstack[out]" -map '[out]' -y out.mp4
```

But it still does not work. Is there a way?

Thank you!

Comment: The effect is called a wipe, in this case, a horizontal wipe. See https://video.stackexchange.com/a/22406/ for a similar effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [xfade filter](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Xfade):

```
ffmpeg -i video1.mp4 -i video2.mp4 -filter_complex "xfade=transition=wiperight:duration=5:offset=1" output.mp4
```

- `transition` chooses the style/effect.
- `duration` is how long the transition lasts.
- `offset` is number of seconds before transition begins.